# echo text on twitter bootstrap modal based on data-id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am passing `data-id` to twitter bootstrap model and I can assign that to a hidden field just fine however based on what `data-id` has, I am trying to echo a text and I am stuck

This is how I am calling the modal, you will notice the first link is passing `goal_holidays` in `data-id` and the second one is passing `goal_house` in `data-id`

```
<a class="open-GoalDialog" data-toggle="modal" href="#editGoals" data-id="goal_holidays">Edit</a>

<a class="open-GoalDialog" data-toggle="modal" href="#editGoals" data-id="goal_house">Edit</a>
```

**What I need to do**
On the modal i need to put a check like this. Please note that this is not the actual code i am using, this is the dummy code i wrote to explain what i need to do

```
if(data-id = goal_holidays){
echo "holiday";
}else if (data-id = goal_house){
echo "house";
}
```

This is what my modal looks like

```
<div id="editGoals" class="modal hide fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a>

        <h3 style="font-size: 18px;" id="myModalLabel"><img src="assets/img/logo_icon.png">Goal Tracker</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="message2"></div>
        <form action="dashboard-goals-ajax.php" method="post" name="goaldataform" id="goaldataform"
              class="form-horizontal goaldataform">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label goal_label_text"><?php _e('Goal Target'); ?>
                </label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                        <span class="add-on">$</span><input type="text" class="input-medium" name="goal_target"
                                                            id="goal_target" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label goal_label_text"><?php _e('How much have you saved towards your goal?'); ?>
                </label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                        <span class="add-on">$</span><input type="text" class="input-medium" name="goal_progress"
                                                            id="goal_progress" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label goal_label_text"><?php _e('Goal deadline'); ?>
                </label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                        <span class="add-on"></span><input class="input-medium datex" type="text" id="goalDeadline"
                                                           name="goalDeadline">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="goal_type" id="goal_type" value=""/>
            <input type="hidden" name="goal_target_submitted">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-complete-text="Close" class="dt-btn btn-yellow dt-btn-1 pull-right"
                id="goaldatasubmit" name="goaldatasubmit"><?php _e('Submit'); ?></button>


        <div class="gap-10"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the JS I am using the assign the `data-id` to hidden field `goal_type`

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-GoalDialog", function () {
    var myGoal = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #goal_type").val(myGoal);
```

I will really appreciate if anyone can help me in how to echo a text based on the `goal_type` data.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your comparisonpart.

```
if(data-id = goal_holidays){
    echo "holiday";
}else if (data-id = goal_house){
    echo "house";
}
```

`goal_holidays` and `goal_house` are strings, not variables.

So, you have to replace the code like that;

```
if(data-id == "goal_holidays"){
    echo "holiday";
}else if (data-id == "goal_house"){
    echo "house";
}
```

Comment: this is not the actual code i am using, this is the dummy code i wrote to explain what i need to do :)